# java scenebuilder bmi calculator

Tags: java, class, controller, scenebuilder

so I've been working on a javaFX & Scenebuilder project to create a BMI calculator, and seem to have gotten a bit stuck. Any tips/recommendations about what I should do?

One of the requirements was to have two interactive classes as well as the controller, fxml page and app launcher. The first class is used to convert inches to cm, and lbs to kg, which is then used in the second class to calculate the bmi value and status.

```
public class BMIInput {

private double heightIN;
private double heightCM;
private double weightKG;
private double weightLBS;
public double height;
public double weight;

public BMIInput() {
}

public double getHeight() {
    if (heightIN == 0) {
        height = heightCM;
    } else if (heightCM == 0) {
        height = (heightIN * 2.54);
    }
    return height;
}

public double getWeight() {
    if (weightLBS == 0) {
        weight = weightKG;
    } else if (weightKG == 0) {
        weight = (weightLBS / 2.205);
    }
    return weight;
}

public double setHeightIN(double height) {
    return this.heightIN = height;
}

public double setHeightCM(double height) {
    return this.heightCM = height;
}

public double setWeightKG(double weight) {
    return this.weightKG = weight;
}

public double setWeightLBS(double weight) {
    return this.weightLBS = weight;
}
```

}

Second class:

```
public class BMICalculator {

BMIInput height;
BMIInput weight;
double bmiValue;

public double getBmiValue() {
    return bmiValue;
}

public void setBmiValue(double bmiValue) {
    this.bmiValue = bmiValue;
}

public double calculateBMI() {
    double heightDouble = Double.parseDouble(height.toString());
    double weightDouble = Double.parseDouble(weight.toString());

    bmiValue = (weightDouble / (heightDouble / 100.0) * (heightDouble / 100));

    return bmiValue;
}    

public String calculateStatus() {
    String value = "";
    if (bmiValue <= 18.5) {
        value = "Underweight";
    } else if (18.6 <= bmiValue && bmiValue <= 24.9) {
        value = "Normal weight";
    } else if (25 <= bmiValue && bmiValue <= 29.9) {
        value = "Overweight";
    } else {
        value = "Obesity";
    }
    return value;
}
```

And the controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML; import javafx.scene.control.Button; import javafx.scene.control.TextField; public class AppController {

@FXML private TextField CMheightInput;
@FXML private TextField INheightInput;
@FXML private TextField KGweightInput;
@FXML private TextField LBSweightInput;
@FXML private Button buttonCalculate;
@FXML private TextField bmiValueOutput;
@FXML private TextField bmiStatusOutput;



BMICalculator calc = new BMICalculator();
BMIInput input = new BMIInput();

@FXML public void calculateBMI() {
    try {
        input.setHeightCM(Double.parseDouble(CMheightInput.getText()));
        input.setHeightIN(Double.parseDouble(INheightInput.getText()));
        input.setWeightKG(Double.parseDouble(KGweightInput.getText()));
        input.setWeightLBS(Double.parseDouble(LBSweightInput.getText()));

        bmiValueOutput.setText("" + calc.calculateBMI());

        bmiStatusOutput.setText("" + calc.calculateStatus());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong, try again.");
    }
}
```

If anyone has any pointers I'd be incredibly grateful! Xx

Comment: Can you tell me why you name a class responsible for converting `BMIInput`? That does not reflect what the class does... By the way, what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: We had to have minimum two classes with interacting code, so I thought it would be logical to have the BMIInput convert the inches and pounds to cm and kg, and because you only have either cm or inches (and not both at the same time), I could use the if-sentence to create a new height variable, which can be used in BMICalculator to calculate the actual BMI value.The problem is that the code complies but nothing happens when I type in values in Scenebuilder.

Comment: The SceneBuilder is just a tool for creating GUIs, you cannot have any logic there. What exactly are you trying to do? Can't you just start implementing the logic in pure Java, test it and then create a GUI around?

Comment: I created the classes first, with the logic, and I don't really have any logic in Scenebuilder - the controller connects the classes with the fxml page, and there I only call on the classes to do the calculations. I've been trying to figure out if I've made any mistakes in connecting the GUI and the code, since each time I run it, I only get thrown the exception. I'll try going back to just ignoring the GUI and see if the code in itself is ok, though - thanks

Comment: Post the `Exception` along with its (complete) stack trace, please.

Comment: In case you just see the error message `"Something went wrong, try again."`, consider putting a `e.printStackTrace()` below the line `System.out.println("Something went wrong, try again.");`, then *try again*.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't referencing the instance of your variables...where is your Main method where the program starts?  You have to load your FXMLController and it's resources in a Java file.  Try looking at a YouTube video on how to use a simple JavaFX program with SceneBuilder.  One of the one's I like is: [How to use SceneBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvgWgpGZVKc)